# document.getElementById in Computed Property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component with v-if which is true/visible in some point of time.

Inside a computed property I would like to get the height of this component, but somehow getElementById does not work inside the computed property, even though it works as a method.

```
  computedProp: function() {
     let element = document.getElementById("prop-id")
     let style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
     return style.getPropertyValue("height")
},
```

> element is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM elements with their different changes are not reactive, so they will not trigger the computed property, but you could take advantage of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver)
to watch any change in the observed element :

```
 data: () => ({
    computedPropHeight: 0,
    observer: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
   let element = document.getElementById("prop-id")
    this.observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation) {
         let style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
          this.computedProp = style.getPropertyValue("height")           
        }
      });
    });
    this.observer.observe(element, {attributes: true});

  },
 beforeDestroy(){
   this.observer.disconnect()
 }
```