# Component rendered multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am separating blocks with a `v-if`-statement like:

```
<div v-if="resp > 1023">
    <PdfViewer />
</div>

<div v-else>
    <PdfViewer />
</div>
```

The problem I got is when viewing it on smaller screen widths PdfViewer gets rendered one time. On  widths over 1023px it's rendered two times even if the second mention of it is in the if-else block. Other html elements inside it ain't shown, but the component is.

Resp is the screen width on mount:

```
    mounted() {
        this.resp = window.innerWidth;
        console.log(this.resp);
    }
```

Comment: Remove **"** after **v-else**

Comment: @Radeanu That wasn't the problem. Just a typo in the question, sry.

Comment: please share the code of `resp` property

Comment: I am guessing that's the initial state where resp is '' or undefined

Comment: @JayLi I assigned 0 to resp at declaring. If I change it to 1024 the problem is just the other way around.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68349293/8172857

Comment: Can you create an demonstration **repo** ?

Comment: maybe you can try only load the component when width is determined?

Comment: @Radeanu that's not possible there sorry. The problem is the inital value of `resp` then. Any workoround for that?

Comment: changed `mounted` to `created`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by assigning the value in the created lifecycle hook, so the value gets set before v-if evaluates.

```
created() {
    this.resp = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(this.resp);
}
```